# Error in compiling before linking the object files using gcc

Tags: c, gcc, command-line

I have source files written in C programming using notepad++ and I am running them from command lines and later i need to link them inorder to generate the .exe file.

Here are the following commands I want to use while generating .exe file

```
gcc logc.c -o logc
gcc mainc.c -o mainc

gcc -o output logc.o mainc.o
```

But when i run the following command my compiler is returning with the following error status.

```
gcc logc.c -o logc

(x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x39): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
```

when i run the following command to compile my mainc file

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccskY3nf.o:mainc.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `Log'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And here are my mainc.c and logc.c and logc.h files for your reference

logc.c file is here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "logc.h"

void InitLog()
{
    Log("Initializing Log");
}

void Log(const char* message)
{
    printf(" %s",message);

}
```

mainc.c file is here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "logc.h"

    int main()
    {
        int x = 5;
        bool comparisonResult = x == 5;
        if(comparisonResult == 1)
            Log("Hello World"); 
        return 0;
    }
```

and logc.h file is here

```
#ifndef _LOG_H
#define _LOG_H

void InitLog();
void Log(const char* message);

#endif
```

How can i compile individual source files and then link them and generate an executable file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but symbols starting with an underscore and followed by an upper-case letter (like e.g. `_LOG_H`) are reserved for the compiler and standard library implementations in all scopes. You should not use such symbols.

Comment: When compiling, always enable the warnings,  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  also strongly suggest using the parameter: `-ggdb` to make it easy to debug with the `gdb` compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't create object files, for that you need the `-c` argument:

```
gcc logc.c -c
gcc mainc.c -c

gcc -o output logc.o mainc.o
```

Answer (score 0):

By default gcc will generate an executable file, not an object file.  So when you compile logc.c, it tries to make an executable but it can't find the `main` function so it fails.  Similarly with main.c, it tries to make an executable but can't find `Log`

You need to add the `-c` option to create object files:

```
gcc logc.c -c -o logc.o
gcc mainc.c -c -o mainc.o
```

Comment: `-o logc.o` is the default here.

Comment: Yes, these commands solved my problem. How can i do the same using g++ compiler to convert another cpp source files and link them and generate executable

Comment: @Abhi12 The options are the same as gcc in this case.